# Could coral float?

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, sea-creatures

I've been thinking about worlds like *[Keplar-62e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler-62e)*, thought to be covered in deep oceans, and wondering about floating reefs.  Could a bio-structure substantially similar to terrestrial coral hold enough gas pockets, preferably in the form of bio-generated Hydrogen, to float neutral-buoyant close to the surface or does the math just not hold up?

Edit: Pumice has been pointed out to me, how embarrassing, but I'm looking for something with less porosity and greater bulk strength to form a floating reef that will largely withstand extremes of weather etc...

Comment: Why hydrogen? Any gas is so much lighter than water that the difference betwen hydrogen, oxygen and carbon dioxide is irrelevant for purposes of buoyancy. And since there are [buoyant rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumice), I cannot see a reason why the skeleton of a coral colony couldn't be buoyant too.

Comment: @AlexP Because hydrogen would be the least pocket for the most buoyancy, which would reduce structural issues arising, also it's one of the easier gases to justify in a biological system. And here's me with a background in Earth Science and I didn't even _think_ of Pumice! I've been wracking my brain about this for at least a week, thank you.

Comment: The difference in the buoyancy of hydrogen and nitrogen or carbon dioxide in water is minuscule, much smaller than the difference in buoyancy caused by the variations in water salinity or temperature. And N2 or CO2 are even easier to justify in biological context; that's what fills the buoyancy chambers of the [nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus) for example. And where I live pumice or pumice-like artificial stones are used as an abrasive in the bathroom -- it's an everyday material.

Comment: @AlexP Hmm, live and learn, Nitrogen huh, how is that even a thing? I'll look at it later, time for bed.

Comment: The composition of chamber gas is, apparently, similar to air but with less oxygen, significantly more carbon dioxide and a whopping 1% argon. The nitrogen oxygen and carbon dioxide are easy, they come disolved in the sea water. No idea where the argon comes from...

Comment: Dry coral already can float because its inner cells become air filled. So if you add a few air bladders it could float.

Comment: You should use either [science-based] or [reality-check] for a question, not both. One implies you are searching for ways and one implies you want feedback on whether your proposed idea is plausible.

Comment: Well, the Portuguese man o' war floats across the ocean, and Kelp has got gas-filled bladders. So, there are floating bio-structures on this planet already! But someone better at biology and physics should perhaps translate this to coral :).

Comment: @Secespitus Except the question does ask both those things, at least it should.

Comment: @Ash, [tag:reality-check] is a lower standard than [tag:science-based] but they're both points on the same scale. Reality check says "I've invented this thing, does it logically make sense", but the rules can be your own. Science based requires it to act by actual rules.

Comment: @Separatrix That's not how the information about the tags _actually_ reads. Reality-check comes across as being purely about the internal logical consistency of the question where Science-based is about whether the laws we know allow a thing to be, or _how_ a thing can be within those laws. I'm not saying that it's not the intent that they be on the same scale but they don't actually read like they are.

Comment: Reality-check does say it contrasts with science-based and hard-science, but consider them as three points along the scale from internal consistency to fully sourced published scientific papers. You never want more than one of the three on a question.

Comment: @Separatrix Grumpy noises, I'm not convinced by this argument _at all_ but that's probably just the asperger's literal mindedness talking, I'll look at it as a sliding scale but I maintain they _read_ as parallel scales.

Comment: Grumpy noises heard and understood, but now you understand what they are, could you word them better? (Do you have access to?) This is more suited to meta at this point.

Comment: @Separatrix Yeah I'm framing a Meta question about this while I work on other things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64246/discussion-between-ash-and-separatrix).

Comment: Pumice doesn't float in the long run anyway. too much pore connection.

Comment: I added [tag:sea-creatures] because coral is an animal.  Pumice is of course a rock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

Coral is sensitive to depth and temperature, very sensitive to temperature. Ocean currents aren't so forgiving.

Basic requirements 18-27m, clear warm waters.

That would require them not to just float but to be neutrally buoyant at a specific depth, not easy to do when you're basically a rock. Staying in warm water is also difficult when you're a at the mercy of the currents. Your coral is very quickly going to find itself at the centre of one of the gyres (a.k.a. the garbage patches) or in cold waters at the end of a warm water current.

Coral already has difficulty surviving storms and a big storm can do a lot of damage to a reef. Without a solid rock base, and at the mercy of the rolling waves, your reef isn't going to survive long even just in deep ocean before the real storms hit. Flexibility is the key to surviving a storm, an attempt to build a large coral reef like structure will result in large waves breaking it up then the subsequent waves smashing it against itself until there's nothing but sand.

Comment: So floating yes, surviving no.

Comment: Yeah, that was essentially my thought too. Making it float is simple, but it just makes it far more vulnerable to the weather and currents compared to sitting on the sea bed.

Comment: But the OP is asking about coral-like organisms, not corals as they exist on Earth.  So there are, for instance, diatoms which have cell walls of SiO2, and which can form colonies.  There are also examples of floating islands on Earth, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_island

Comment: @jamesqf, those floating islands are inland, there's no reason to think they'd survive ocean waves. I've ignored some important features of coral to get this far, one being that corals are territorial and have little battles over space.

Comment: @Separatrix: There are free-floating mats of seaweed, e.g. https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/sargassosea.html  Doesn't seem like it would take much of an evolutionary nudge to send them down a path that evolved into free-floating islands, perhaps incorporating harder parts from coral-like organisms.  Because we aren't limited to Earth corals, but alien organisms that are somewhat coral-like.

Comment: @jamesqf, write it up then, the question is still open for more answers. For my purposes I have only picked a few aspects of coral, they like daylight, they like water within a narrow temperature range, and they build rigid structures. As I mentioned in this answer, the Sargasso Sea lies within one of the gyres and it's highly flexible.

Comment: @MattBowyer The problem is that there's no seabed in range, thus the question.

Comment: @Ash, I'm trying to think of a way to make it work, but the only solution seems to be to make it utterly unlike coral, i.e. soft, fast growing, surface dwelling. Like Sargassum for example.

Comment: @Separatrix Yup and I thank you for your efforts. Does mean wave frequency and amplitude make any difference to the structural requirements or is it peak loading that's the controlling limit?

Comment: @jamesqf Did you read Separatrix's Comment? It's a thought worth writing up.

Comment: @Ash, waves are largely a surface effect, coral growing so far down is normally unaffected by anything but the larger storms which means when it gets hit, it's hit hard.

Comment: @Separatrix Okay yup so peak loading is all that matters because there is no other kind.

Answer (score 3):

I have found floating coral skeleton fragments while beachcombing, the largest perhaps 2-3 kilos. The coral polyps themselves were long gone, so the coral was "dead" but all four fragments I've found over the years had since been colonized by algae and gooseneck barnacles. I've never cut one open, but it's been theorized that these fragments had once been washed ashore elsewhere, dried out and somehow hollowed out inside, and then somehow again washed back into the sea.  Very interesting phenomena.

Comment: So floating reef-like structure colonising old dead coral is not impossible, cool thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

### Give it gas sacs

The Portuguese Man o' War is a colonial organism that superficially resembles a jellyfish.  One of its component units forms a gas sac that allows it to float at the surface of the water. When it is in danger, the man o' war can deflate its sac to sink below the surface. It has no other means of propulsion.

Corals are also colonial organisms. Each polyp has a hard skeleton but inside is a soft animal. It is possible in theory for one polyp out of a certain number to develop into a large floating balloon, allowing the organism to move. It could use these to float and sink depending on conditions like weather and temperature. It may evolve like this in order to avoid large, slow-moving coral eaters that are bound to the sea floor, like giant starfish.

How would such an organism form a "floating reef"? I'm picturing a kind of branching and interlocking lattice, somewhat flat and with many "holes" that can be filled with the inflated polyps when the reef wants to float - like a giant sheet of bubble-wrap where the spaces in between the bubbles are hard coral. A person may be able to walk around on it provided they only step on the "hard" parts and avoid popping the balloons, and also avoid distressing the colony to the point where it would sink to escape.

However, the thickness of these "reefs" would be limited.  Real corals grow huge because the living polyps grow on top of layers and layers of dead ones. But these floating corals cannot do this, otherwise there will be a certain point where the living balloon polyps can no longer lift the layers of skeletons they grow on.  At some point the colony will have to break apart or shed their lower layers.